# Spring MVC AngularJS routing not working

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, routes

Spring MVC - AngularJS routing example doesn't work.

I'm getting `404 not found (not found page)`. How to resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: without posting code or any related stuff we can't ask the questions like this. there may be issue with your route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not acquainted with the Spring framework, but I may know what the issue is since it's just a 404 error. In your routes `templateUrl` looks for the html template relative to the index file, or the file that is launched as the home page. So for example, if that file is in the parent folder you have to provide the proper path with `templateUrl: 'views/about.jsp'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<%@ page session="false"%>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

<!-- SPELLS -->
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngRoute' ]);
    myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'views/home.jsp',
            controller : 'myController'
        }).when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'views/about.jsp',
            controller : 'aboutController'
        }).when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'views/contact.jsp',
            controller : 'contactController'
        });
    });
    myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
    });
    myApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
    });
    myApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
    {{1+1}}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header"></div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="main">

        <!-- angular templating -->
        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
        <div ng-view></div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem in my path.Thank you everyone.